# jquery multiple file upload working locally but not in windows server

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I am trying to upload a file from html 5 using wcf rest and jquery.its working fine in local.but not in server.kindly help me to solve this issue.

my js code is

```
function UploadFile() {
    var ajaxdata = new FormData();
    ajaxdata.append('action', 'col-xs-12 mid_forma');
    $.each($("input[type=file]"), function (i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {
            ajaxdata.append('photo[' + i + ']', file);
        })
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: HostingInvestmentURL + 'UploadFileNew/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ajaxdata,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //alert('Added Successfully');

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Some error Occurred!');
        }
    });
}
```

my service is

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadFileNew", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

I got the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load...   The request was redirected to....
>   which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

> When cross-domain access is enabled, the server should respond back to
>   OPTIONS and allow the request to go through. This should return HTTP
>   200 unless there are other errors. But ajax callback will not be able
>   to access the response. This can be done now only if
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to "*" or the Origin request header
>   value, and the Access-Control as needed. And the ajax callback will
>   receive the response as intended.

Follow this link it may helpful to you [What can I do to make this cross-domain request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22392926/2798643)

Comment: Thanks Raj for ur reply.but i have added these things in my Global.asax.cs file

Comment: protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
       HttpContext.Current.Response.End();